# Is there an open source status reporting system?

Tags: open-source, productivity

Anyone know of an open-source system for sending out 'what tasks did you to today' type status report reminders in email, then collecting them in an internal website?

I checked on freshmeat but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [DotProject](http://www.dotproject.net/).  Personally we use [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/), we have configured it to track tasks other then bugs and send out reminders etc.